# How to configure kile to run texlive 2011?

Tags: texlive, kile

I install TeX Live 2011 in Linux, but i can not configure kile to run the TL11. Can you explain step by step, please?

Solved:

$gedit ~/.profile

and digit

PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/i386-linux:$PATH; export PATH 
MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf/doc/man:$MANPATH; export MANPATH 
INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf/doc/info:$INFOPATH; export INFOPATH

or

PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH; export PATH

for 64 bits.

Comment: We'd like to keep answers separate from questions, so you should write a separate answer instead of editing your answer into the question. Self-answers are perfectly admissible, and a well-written answer may earn you additional reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kile uses only commands like pdflatex. So you have to check whether the symbolic links are created.

Type in the terminal:
`latex -v`

The result should be:

```
marco@ubuntu:~$ latex -v
pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011)
kpathsea version 6.0.1
```

I guess you don't get this output. In this case the [TeXLive documentation](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-310003.4) is your friend.

Comment: @Marco I just installed [TexLive 2011 from the sources](http://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html) without having an older version on Maverick. Now I would like to install Kile without installing the old TexLive that apt whats to install when I try to install Kile via ppa. The same dependency problems occur when I want to install [Kile from the sources](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kile/files/stable/). How is it possible to discard to install the old TexLive version?

Comment: @JJD: You can install Kile by the terminal: Please see apt-get install.

Comment: @Marco I know. But that includes dependencies which result in installing the old version of TexLive.

Comment: @JJD: No first you must download the file with sudo apt-get download and then use dpgk.

Comment: @Marco But still it will download 679MB as you can see in this [screenshot](http://goo.gl/jsLlF).

Comment: @JJD: I use (ubunut 11.04):`cd $HOME/Downloads && sudo apt-get download kile`. Now you have download kile into the folder and you can use dpgk. (Do you want to see an image?)

Comment: In the end these tutorials helped me to successfully manually install [TexLive 2011](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Baustelle/Tex_Live) and [Kile 2.1.0.](http://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/kile-mit-texlive/) on Ubuntu 10.10. Thank you again!

Answer (score 6):

put the following script as `zzzz-texlive.sh` into the directory `/etc/profile.d/`:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/`uname -i`-linux:$PATH
export MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf/doc/man:$MANPATH
export INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf/doc/info:$INFOPATH
unset TEXINPUTS
unset TEXMFCONFIG
```

and restart the system

Comment: You do not need to reboot. Just log out and in again, that should do it.

Comment: true and that was what I meant ...

Comment: Where does the "zzzz" prefix come from?

Comment: The ifiles n that directory are executed in alphabetical order. With zzzz we can be sure that it will be one of the last ones

Answer (score 2):

For the ubuntu 12.04, there is a PPA available:
https://launchpad.net/~texlive-backports/+archive/ppa

To install the repository, type in terminal:
    `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:texlive-backports/ppa`

Then you can install latex as usual (there are a lot of guides on the web). To check the version of latex you are using type, in the terminal:
    `latex -v`