# TeX Live with Kile in Ubuntu

Tags: installing, texlive, ubuntu, paths, kile

I have found [How to configure kile to run texlive 2011?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23869/how-to-configure-kile-to-run-texlive-2011) and this is my problem.

I have installed Ubuntu's TeXLive with `sudo apt-get install texlive` and TeXLive 2011 using [the net installer from CTAN](http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz) (There says there is no problem have both installations). I tried `latex -v` and I found

```
pdfTeX 3.1415926-1.40.10-2.2 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
kpathsea version 5.0.0
Copyright 2009 Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
Compiled with libpng 1.2.42; using libpng 1.2.42
Compiled with zlib 1.2.3.3; using zlib 1.2.3.3
Compiled with poppler version 0.12.4
```

and did put the following script as `zzzz-texlive.sh` into the directory `/etc/profile.d/`:

```bsh
export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/`uname -i`-linux:$PATH
export MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf/doc/man:$MANPATH
export INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf/doc/info:$INFOPATH
unset TEXINPUTS
unset TEXMFCONFIG
```

and restarted the system.

As explain in [by the net installer](http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz), restarted the system but `latex -v` says *TeX Live 2009/Debian* like in the first time.

So, I think I'm not using TeX Live 2011.

How can I use this TeX Live packages in my Ubuntu 10.04 LTS?

Comment: Also related: [How to install “vanilla” TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu) and [How to add a directory to my path?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path) (on our sister site http://askubuntu.com).

Comment: What does `echo $PATH` print in the terminal? Does it include the TL 2011 path? Your `zzzz-texlive.sh` script might not be executed for some reason. Check if it is readable for all (`chmod +r zzzz-texlive.sh` to make it so).

Comment: My `uname -i` returns unknown... so the scripts works wrong...how should I put the hardware plataform? (I have a Ubuntu 10.04 LTS amd64 2.6.32-33-generic)...

Comment: I have installed TeX Live with the net install as says in [How to install “vanilla” TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite strange that `uname -i` gives "unknown". However, the TeX Live installer should have guessed your architecture. So, look at the output of

```
ls /usr/local/texlive/2011/bin
```

and use that; since you're on a 64 bit machine, it should be

```
x86_64-linux
```

so the first line to be saved in `zzzz-texlive.sh` should be

```
export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH
```

A logout-login cycle should be sufficient to make the new setting work.

Comment: Thx! Worked. `latex -v` returned
pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011)

Answer (score 4):

After installing TeXLive2011 type in your case (Ubuntu 64 bits),

> $gedit ~/.profile

and type in the file

> PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH; export PATH 
>   MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf/doc/man:$MANPATH; export MANPATH
>   INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf/doc/info:$INFOPATH; export
>   INFOPATH

and restart.
Tell me if it worked.

Comment: Thx too `@Regis da Silva`!