# latex/xelatex works from command line, but not from Kile

Tags: xetex, texlive, kile

I installed Kile and Texlive 2011.

I wrote a very simple test document:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine}
\begin{document}
Русский: Числовые выражения

English: Number expressions
\end{document}
```

When I run `$ xelatex myfile.tex` from command line it is properly compiled to pdf file.

But when I try to build it from Kile, it throws an error `File xltxtra.sty not found.`

How should I configure Kile or Texlive installation, so things work properly?
My OS is Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: Have you set any environment variables in Kile? (See Configure-Kile => LaTeX => General).

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I didn't set any env variables in Kile, but your comment helped me to solve the problem. The problem was I put updates to PATH, MANPATH and INFOPATH variables into the `~/.bashrc` file, but they should be put into a separate script in `/etc/profile.d/` directory, because `.bashrc` is only executed by interactive shells.

Comment: See [TeX Live with Kile in Ubuntu][1]


  [1]: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31858/tex-live-with-kile-in-ubuntu/31879#31879

on 32 bits use: i386-linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OP installed TeX Live without automatic creation of symbolic links. In this case he must set set the path of TeX Live.

The problem is solved in the thread:
[tlmgr is not accessible after installing TeX Live 2011 on a Ubuntu system](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26624/tlmgr-is-not-accessible-after-installing-tex-live-2011-on-a-ubuntu-system)

You can also set the path in Kile. 
*Settings ==> Configure - Kile ==> LaTeX ==> General*

Here a screen shot:
[image]

Of course the first method is recommended.