# PGF doesn't work under Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, ubuntu

I updated my Ubuntu to the newest version 11.10 recently. Today when I use PGF again, i find many of my old examples cannot compile. It always give the error information as:

```
! Package PGF Math Error: The function `reciprocal' already exists.

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H &lt;return&gt;  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.156 ...@\pgfmath@reciprocaltemp0000000\pgfmath@}


! Package PGF Math Error: The function `div' already exists.

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H &lt;return&gt;  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.212 }


! Package PGF Math Error: The function `mod' already exists.

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H &lt;return&gt;  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.228 }
```

Does anyone have the same problem?

EDIT: I have followed the suggestions by many people here that I have installed TeXLive 2011 manually and updated the path, and logout and login again. The sad thing is that the problem still exists. I am wondering whether the problem really comes from the TeXlive 2009? :-(

Comment: As most people find out the hard way, Ubuntu ships with the *ancient* TeXlive 2009 (because that's what Debian does)

Comment: Thanks Kahen. Do you know a solution? Shall I install TeXlive 2011?

Comment: If you have the hard drive space for it, installing TeXlive 2011 manually to `/usr/local/texlive/` isn't a terrible idea. But in order to not confuse `dpkg`, you can't uninstall Ubuntu's TeXlive 2009 (not without a *lot* of manual intervention at least). When it's installed there, make symlinks (`ln -s`) to the TeXlive 2011 binaries in /usr/local/bin and you'll be good to go (I think... I haven't done this myself)

Comment: Thanks Kahen, I am now installing TeXlive 2011 now. I will see whether it helps. :-)

Comment: I have installed TeXlive 2011. Do you know how to make the symbolic link? I find my pdftex under /usr/bin, instead of /usr/local/bin

Comment: The binaries should be in `/usr/local/texlive/2011/⟨OSNAME⟩/bin` or something like that, where `⟨OSNAME⟩` is the name of the system (e.g. `win32` on Windows). So you'd do something like this (as root): `cd /usr/local/texlive/2011/⟨OSNAME⟩/bin/; for $BINARY in *; do if [ -x $BINARY ]; then; ln -s $BINARY /usr/local/bin/$BINARY; fi; done`.  The alternative is to edit /etc/profile to add TeXlive 2011's binary directory to the beginning of your $PATH.

Comment: Thanks Kahen. I updated my /etc/profile by adding the following line PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH, it seems not working...

Comment: `/etc/profile` is read on login (or when it's manually sourced, of course). Logout and back in again. Also, the line should probably be something like this instead: `[ -d /usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux ] && PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux:${PATH}`

Comment: @kahen: TUG has pretty concise [instructions on replacing the Debian-provided TeX Live with the upstream one](http://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html). You just make a dummy package that "Provides" all the TeX-related things other Debian packages might depend on.

Comment: @kahen I would *not* recommend making symbolic links in `/usr/local/bin` as they might be overwritten by an update of the Ubuntu TeX packages. It's better to change `.profile` or adding a file in `/etc/profile.d` as explained [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23869/how-to-configure-kile-to-run-texlive-2011/23880#23880)

Comment: @egreg no, `dpkg` doesn't touch `/usr/local.` Ubuntu's TeX binaries are in `/usr/bin.`

Comment: It is sad that after updating the link and login again. Even my normal tex files have compiling problems. Some packages are missing. This is not a big deal I think. But the PGF file still couldn't be complied. The same problem remains. :-(  I really regretted to have updated to Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: @kahen Right; but I wouldn't recommend the symbolic links nontheless. The `profile.d` way is surely neater and easier.

Comment: See also [How to install “vanilla” TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu) for help with the installation of the normal TeXLive.

Comment: @egreg: It is really a matter of opinion, by I would say that making symlinks in /usr/local/bin is definitely the "unixy" way of doing it. The package manager will never touch anything under `/usr/local`, and the binaries will be accessible to everybody, no matter what shell they are using.

Comment: I didn't realize until now that you did have a working pgf before the Ubuntu upgrade.  That's interesting, I wonder what changed TeXwise in the latest Ubuntu.

Comment: @Jan Hlavacek, yes, I worked with PGF for more than one year. I got this problem only after my updating my Ubuntu to 11.10 recently.

Comment: The problem is that I have tried to install TeXlive 2011 and update the path. But the problem still exists. :-(

Comment: The "already defined" makes me wonder if something is being loaded from the Ubuntu version.  Check your log file for any files under /usr/share, those indicate that tex is loading some files from the Ubuntu version of TL which it shouldn't.  (I run TL2011 on a Debian system with no troubles so I know that it is possible to mix them.)

Comment: Posting the log file could help, we could see what files are being loaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could update your PGF version, either

- get it from [CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) if this stable one is newer than yours from the Ubuntu repositories,
- get [PGF from CVS](http://sourceforge.net/cvs/?group_id=142562),
- or get a build (TDS archive) from [Paul's webpage](http://perso.mines-albi.fr/~gaborit/latex/pgf_2.10-CVS.tds.zip).

If the problem persists, check which related packages you are using, such as `pgfplots`, which could cause the problem. Identify (by commenting out) and update, if necessary, to get a version which is compatible to your PGF version.

Note that the [tlcontrib](http://tlcontrib.metatex.org/usage.html) texlive repository has an up to date version of pgf-cvs but you cannot use it for two reasons:

- the `tlmgr` is disabled with debian/ubuntu packaged texlive;
- the [tlcontrib](http://tlcontrib.metatex.org/usage.html) repository works only with texlive 2010 and texlive 2011.

Comment: I reinstalled PGF version 2.10.1. The problem still exists.

Comment: You can see it in your `.log` file, if necessary add the `\listfiles` command to your document.

Comment: Thanks Stefan. Here it is:
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian) (format=pdflatex 2011.4.30)  19 JUL 2011 13:29

Comment: @Anand I extended my answer.

Comment: @Anand Yes, 2009 packages mixed with more current packages could cause it. I fully support Kahens suggestion to install TL 2011. I'm using 2011 on Ubuntu as well.

Comment: @Anand yes, also, however at this moment it's a 11.04 system. Btw. I suggest let's clean up and remove some comments afterwards.

Comment: You could also try to install pgf 2.10.1 and remove the debian pgf packages. Debian (and, I suppose, Ubuntu) packages pgf separately from the rest of TeXLive, so you should be able to remove them using your favorite package manager.  I used to run pgf 2.10.0 with Debian's TeXLive 2009 without any problems.  Something may have changed in 2.10.1, though.

Comment: Thanks Jan Hlavacek. My version is PGF 2.10.1 indeed. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I tried on another computer with Ubuntu 11.10 and everything the same as my computer. I downloaded one example from PGF site and it works well!!! So I come back to check my PGF files. After removing the line

```
\usepackage{pgfmath}
```

It works again in my system!

Thank you a lot for your patient answers and warm-hearted helps! Special thanks go to  Kahen and Stefan Kottwitz. Thank you very much!

Comment: So the problem was that you were loading `pgfmath` twice!  Hence all the `already defined` error messages.  (Strange that `pgfmath` doesn't test to see if it's already been loaded or not.)

Comment: How can I prevent it being loaded twice?

Comment: Err ... don't load it twice?  Seriously, if you are loading any `pgf` packages, they almost certainly load `pgfmath` themselves so you don't need to load it explicitly.  Thus simply omitting the `\usepackage{pgfmath}` will do.

Comment: @AndrewStacey: this is most likely a bug in the pgf package, which should use `\RequirePackage` instead of `\input` when used with LaTeX. However, I don't blame the author, since the business of being compatible both with Plain and LaTeX is always a mess.